# Find an integer n and rational, not integers, r and s such that n= r² + s². Number Theory

Tags: arithmetic

I'm trying to apply theorems that I know, but they're all about integers. I really don't know how to solve this problem, in Number Theory, with rational.

"Find an integer $n$ and rational, not integers, $r$ and $s$ such that $n = r^2 + s^2$"

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

Think about Pythagorean triples. For example, $3^2+4^2=5^2$. Now try dividing that equation by some appropriate number.